# Переделка в мультизагрузку

Tags: php, fileupload

**Обновлено!**
Есть скрипт для загрузки изображения на сервер, но вот незадача. Грузится только 1 изображение, само собой я понимаю что дело в цикле foreach. Как ни выкручивал цикл - ничего не вышло, мне возвращалась ошибка о плохом расширении файла. 
Var_dump выдавал информацию о том, что несколько картинок успешно содержатся в переменной.
HTML Код:

```
  <form action="scripts/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                  <p>             

                      <input type="file" name="image[]" multiple/><br />
                            <input type="hidden"name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
                      <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Upload" />
                  </p>
                  </form>
```

PHP Код:

```
    // вызов файла соединения с базой данных
    require("conn.php");



    // короткая функция, которая распечатывает содержание массива способом, при котором его легко прочитать
    // можно использовать эту функцию во время отладки, но ей можно пренебречь во время работы скрипта
    function showContents($array)
    {
        echo "
";
        print_r($array);
        echo "
";
    }

    // определение некоторых констант

    // в этой переменной - путь к папке изображений, в которой все изображения будут сохраненными
    // обратите внимание на слэш
    $TARGET_PATH = "images/";

    // получение отправленных переменных
foreach($_FILES['image']['name'] as $image){
    var_dump($image);

$file_ext = strrchr(basename($image["name"]), '.');
var_dump($file_ext);

    $image['name'] = mysql_real_escape_string($image['name']);
        $image['name'] = xx().$file_ext;

    // Построение пути, по которому файл будет перемещен
    // т.e.  images/picture.jpg
    $TARGET_PATH .= $image['name'];

    // проверка, заполнены ли все поля формы
    if ($image['name'] == "" )
    {
        $_SESSION['error'] = "Все поля должны быть заполнены";
        header("Location: ../fund_deposit.php");
        exit;
    }

    // проверка, является ли загружаемый файл изображением
    // проверяется тип файла, а не расширение, поскольку расширение легко сфальсифицировать


    // проверка, нет ли в базе данных файла с таким же названием
    // устранение проблем с названием с использованием метки времени
    if (file_exists($TARGET_PATH))
    {
        $_SESSION['error'] = "Файл с таким именем уже существует";
        header("Location: ../fund_deposit.php");
        exit;
    }

    // перемещение файла из временного хранилища в постоянное
    if (move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'],$TARGET_PATH))
    {
        // ВНИМАНИЕ: это место, где очень многие делают ошибки
        // мы не вставляем изображение в базу данных; мы вставляем ссылку на расположение файла на сервере
        $sql = "UPDATE users set filename = '" .$image['name'] . "' where id = '$userid' ";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Невозможно вставить данные в базу: " . mysql_error());
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        // частая причина неудачи в продвижении файла в ошибке в правах доступа к директории, нужны права на запись
        // установите для директории права доступа с записью
        $_SESSION['error'] = "Невозможно загрузить файл.  Проверьте права доступа к директории (чтение/запись)";
        header("Location: ../fund_deposit.php");
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вопросы следуют такому принципу: вы показываете код с ошибкой и вам говорят, в чем ошибка и как правильно. Зачем вы вернули код в состояние, когда ошибки нет и просто нужно переписать код? Перепишите его и вам помогут разобраться с проблемой, если таковая возникнет.

Comment: Обновил, смотрите пост.

Comment: теперь вы, кажется, отрезали кусок php-кода и весь html код

Comment: Упс:) , исправлено.

Comment: А куда кусок с `is_valid_type` дели, который был в самом первом варианте? Это же вроде самое главное, нет? Ошибка же, говорите, "о плохом расширении".

Comment: я вырезал, дабы посмотреть, пустит ли скрипт файлы, итог я получил ошибку о плохих правах на папку. Хотя все отлично заливалось без цикла.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44172/discussion-between-john-doe-and--).

Comment: Видимо, у вас содержимое массива $_FILES отличается от моего. Странно. Выведите его в вар_дамп и скиньте мне в чате.

Answer (score 0):

Так как ваш пример практически не является воспроизводимым, я могу только последовательно указывать на ошибки, пока у вас не заработает.

Обратите внимание, что вы перебираете с помощью `foreach`:

```
foreach($_FILES['image']['name'] as $image){
    var_dump($image);
    $file_ext = strrchr(basename($image["name"]), '.');
    ...
```

У вас даже вар_дамп стоит верный, который вам показывает, что в `$image` у вас строка (имя файла). Так какой такой `$image["name"]` вы пытаетесь получить?

Дальнейший просмотр кода дает понять, что вы не представляете себе структуру массива `$_FILES`. Вот вам пример, который я только что получил у себя:

```
array(1) {
  ["image"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "342323.tif"
      [1]=>
      string(22) "ok_logo_sign_white.png"
    }
    ["type"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "image/tiff"
      [1]=>
      string(9) "image/png"
    }
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(46) "C:\server\PHP-5.4.28-VC9-TS\upload\php2E6C.tmp"
      [1]=>
      string(46) "C:\server\PHP-5.4.28-VC9-TS\upload\php2E8C.tmp"
    }
    ["error"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(0)
      [1]=>
      int(0)
    }
    ["size"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      int(127372)
      [1]=>
      int(10697)
    }
  }
}
```

1 - Открытие цикла переделать на

```
foreach($_FILES['image']['name'] as $index => $imageName){
```

2 - Там, где вы оперируете (внутри цикла) именем файла, вам нужно использовать `$imageName` вместо вашего `$image['name']`.

3 - Там, где вы берете адрес текущего расположения временного файла (`tmp_name`), вы должны брать его из соответствующего места:

```
$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$index]
```

Пока хватит. Если останутся проблемы - пишите.

И не забывайте внимательно смотреть, что выводит `var_dump`. В нем, ведь, все ответы. У меня, кроме этого, еще и кучу ошибок по обращению к несуществующему `name` насыпало.

Comment: Проблема с temp хранилищем. 
    var_dump($image['tmp_name']); - string(1) "L" string(1) "T"; $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$index] - null $image['tmp_name'][$index] - PHP Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in –

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что при успешной загрузке я хотел редиректить, в следствие чего массив разрывался и происходил баг.